# Apache 2.2 / Win7 - slow or not responsive

Tags: php, apache, wamp

My configuration - Windows 7 x64, Php 5.3, Apache 2.2.15, latest Mysql.

When loading pages from localhost, the response time shown by firebug is more 530ms for the main 'index.php' file, sometimes the connection is reset. It's painfully slow.

I googled the problem and found a workaround - switch off and on again a win service called BFE - base filtering engine. Then everything works like a lightning
but xdebug doesn't work in netbeans.

Why is this response time so long? Can you think of any other solution than BFE toggling?

joey33

Answer (score 1):

Just to make users aware, Using the packed apache,php and mysql is great but found when using an SMTP server with this bundle causes problems, using stand alone fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with super slow (never loading) localhost pages when running WAMP 2.4 and using IE10. A hint in [this thread](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,116971) fixed the issue for me.

Add these lines to the bottom of your httpd.conf file

```
# Fix IE crashing Apache 
AcceptFilter http none 
AcceptFilter https none
```

Comment: This fix also worked for me. For background / more info, see:
http://superuser.com/questions/516030/apache-2-4-on-windows-responds-slowly-hangs-when-serving-some-dynamic-pages

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [xamp](http://www.apachefriends.org/fr/xampp-windows.html), which should support xdebug out of the box.

Otherwise you need to [complete your wamp setup with an xdebug dll](http://translate.google.fr/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http://www.gianonatti.com/%3Fp%3D38&sl=fr&tl=en).

> put `php_xdebug-2.0.5-5.3-vc6.dll` in the directory `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0`

Comment: thanks guys for the tip! I'll try with the bundle - in fact you're right, there's no need to give myself extra pain if there's all in one box; I'll post about the results.

Kau-Boy - I understand that you don't have these response lags?

Answer (score 0):

I always used the lastest XAMPP Version from [apachefriends.org](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html) which runs very stable and fast on my Windows 7 x64 machine. It also has Apache 2.2.15, MySQL 5.1.46 and PHP 5.3.2 included.

Is there a reason you use all programs as stand-alones?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I tried xampp and all other sugegstion given in forums but finally reverting win7 to 32bit edition solved the problem.